# 4.7 Install, Database Settings Correct. Still no Contacts

Tags: upgrade, database

I have upgraded from CiviCrm 4.2 to 4.7 now that I finally have it working it will not bring up contacts from the old Civi database. I looked at the setting php file and all the information is correct. What is the best way to troubleshoot this issue. I have checked the database that is was set to use and the information is present. Is there any sort of mapping that the new install needs to do? Please advise and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two civi installs looking at the same db? This won't work!

After copying over the files did you go to [yoursite]/civicrm/update.php

Comment: I removed the files from the install but I was not aware of the update php.

Comment: I just reconnected the database and tried to use the update php as suggested and civil showed a not found page.